# Regular expression for {$w:w$ starts with $0$ and has odd length, or starts with $1$ and has even length}

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Problem in my textbook.

> Give a regular expression for the language
>
> {$w:w$ starts with $0$ and has odd length, or starts with $1$ and has even length}
>
> alphabet is $\{0,1\}^*$

My answer: $(0\cup1(0\cup1))((0\cup1)(0\cup1))^* $

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.